# jQuery Ajax how to tell jquery where to append the html data returned from Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have two ul lists that have the same structure:

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li id="inv-1">
        <label>Item name</label>
        <select>
           <option selected="selected"> value="1">Value 1</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    //...
    <li id="inv-2">
        <label>Item name</label>
        <select>
           <option selected="selected"> value="1">Value 1</option>
        </select>
    </li>
 </ul>
<ul id="list2">
    <li id="inv-44">
        <label>Item name</label>
        <select>
           <option selected="selected"> value="0">Value 0</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    //...
    <li id="inv-55">
        <label>Item name</label>
        <select>
           <option selected="selected"> value="0">Value 0</option>
        </select>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

They both look the same but have different ids. In list 1 I have all li's that have option selected > 0. In the second list I have all the li's with option selected == 0.

I can add more items to the list pressing a button that pops a fancybox asking me for the new name for the new item and the value of the selected option. I need to append the new li item to the proper list after it's included to the database.

My jQuery function goes like this:

```
$(".btn.invi").fancybox({
  afterClose : function() {
    var nombre=$('#addinvi').val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax-invi.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: "id="+idboda+"&name="+name+"&value="+value",
    success: function(data) {
      $('ul#list1').append(data);//How do I know where to append??
    }
    }); 
  }
});
```

How do I tell the success function where to append based on the value of that selected option?

Right now the data returned from ajax-invi.php is something like this (after setting the values with php to the mysql database)

```
    <li id="inv-22">
        <label>Item name</label>
        <select>
           <option selected="selected"> value="1">Value 1</option>
        </select>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

IDs are unique in a page. You have 2 list items with the same id.

```
<ul id="list1">
<li id="inv-1">
    <label>Item name</label>
    <select>
       <option selected="selected"> value="1">Value 1</option>
    </select>
</li>
//...
<li id="inv-2"> //Note the change in ID
    <label>Item name</label>
    <select>
       <option selected="selected"> value="1">Value 1</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Once this change is made, in your success function

```
$(".btn.invi").fancybox({
    afterClose : function() {
    var nombre=$('#addinvi').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax-invi.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data: "id="+idboda+"&name="+name+"&value="+value,
        success: function(data) {
            //perfom your tests here
            //based on your result do either of the following
            $('ul#invlist').find('#inv-1').append(data);
            $('ul#invlist').find('#inv-2').append(data);
        }
     });
```

});

Comment: The duplicated id's were a typo. What tests should I perform? I edited my question.

Comment: That depends on your requirement. How do you decide the data should be appended to a particular section?

Comment: I said in my question, it depends on the value from the selected option. The person chooses something from the list, if its value is 0, it goes to list2, if it's more than 0, to list1. But I'm already returning html from the ajax function so I can't check the value to know where to append

Comment: Where does this fancybox thing work? Do you set this value from it or just the name?

Comment: I add the value in the fancybox and retrieve it here: data: "id="+idboda+"&name="+name+"&value="+value" (value is the one we are looking for)

Answer (score 0):

It will append like you said. In the ul with id "#invlist".

If you want to append it more specifick i think you need to look what the data is and procces it into a stucture before appending it somewhere.

Comment: As I said I have two lists, I don't know how to tell the function where to append depending on that value